# How to install a new PHP extension on IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I have installed PHP 5.2.13 through Web Platform Installer on IIS 7.5/windows 2008 R2
Now I'm trying to install additional PHP extensions, such as mcrypt, so I downloaded the compiled .zip file from the php windows binaries site.
I put the relevant dlls in the extensions folder, and added the lines in the php.ini:

```
[PHP_MCRYPT]
extension=php_mcrypt.dll
```

After restarting IIS, no application was working.
This was with VC6 compiled/non thread-safe compiled version of PHP 5.2.13 .zip package.
I also tried with the thread-safe version, which prevented IIS to restart and forced me to reboot the server.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `php_mcrypt.dll` has a dependency on `libmcrypt.dll`. Did you make
`libmcrypt.dll` available to IIS?

Comment: That was exactly the reason why it wasn't working, as I found out later. Please add that as an answer and I'll choose it! :)
Basically, IIS needs that version of PHP as I have written above, and any extension from that compiled package should work just fine (provided the dependencies are in place too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as **bzlm** commented:

`php_mcrypt.dll` has a dependency on `libmcrypt.dll`. Did you make `libmcrypt.dll` available to IIS?

That was the reason. Thank you!